# Is there a way to monitor/alert on any changes to the private IP address of an ALB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm aware that AWS Application Load Balancers occasionally change their private IP addresses due to maintenance, from what I understand customers are unable to receive prior warning of these changes. I'm currently trying to find a way to monitor/alert on these changes as and when they happen.

Has anybody implemented a similar solution before using CloudWatch/EventBridge/Lambda?

Comment: Why do you care about the private IP of the load balancer? Are you trying to use that IP in security group rules or something?

Comment: The private IP is an implementation detail of the service you shouldn't rely on. Chances are you're solving the wrong problem ;-)

Comment: @MarkB the ALB is called by another service which caches the IP address of the ALB forever once translated via Route53, we are unable to reduce the TTL cache from this. Hence, if the ALB IP were to change then these calls would fail unless we did a manual restart of this service. As a temporary fix/improvement, I was looking into ways we could be alerted of any changes to the IP addresses used by the ALB.

Comment: Your issue feels like it should be solved with DNS, but if you really cant you can use Lambda to periodically poll the ENIs in your VPC with `DescribeNetworkInterfaces` API operation. There are various filters available to narrow down the list (i would look at attached security group and VPC id to identify an ALB). Im not aware of/doubt any notifications exist for the private IPs of the ALB listeners as they are supposed to be transient.

Comment: I had a similar case but I used zabbix with a custom script which does nslookup, put the ip in a file, compare  the recent ip with the ones in the old one, send an alert , replace the old ip with the new one. I think something similar can be done wiht lambda but it needs to run periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is  AWS Managed Service, we have no insight into when this will happen but we can tell when it happens after the fact. In any case this change should not matter and any clients using the ALB as a entry point should respect DNS. Along with this the DNS Record should be set with a TTL of 60 seconds to avoid stale records being returned to the client when the IP does change.

Some methods to alert on this change;

1. When the IP address of the ALB changes, a ENI is created/deleted in the VPC/Subnet in which the new IP address is associated with this, so you can create an EventBridge rule to monitor for any 'CreateNetworkInterface || DeleteNetworkInterface' Actions where the "sourceIPAddress": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com" and/or "requestParameters": {"description": "ELB app/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"} - where the ELB "ELB app/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx" will be replaced by the ELB you wish to monitor these changes for.

A pattern such as the following;

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "sourceIPAddress": ["elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateNetworkInterface","DeleteNetworkInterface"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "description": ["ELB app/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can then set the target of the EventBridge rule as a SNS Topic to alert on this.

Note: To create a rule that triggers on an API call via CloudTrail - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html

2. EventBridge to trigger a Lambda function at a fixed rate of 1 time per minute/hour. The Lambda function fetches the latest ALB/CLB IP addresses by performing DNS lookup and compares them to the previously stored IP addresses in a text file stored on AWS S3. If there is a change in the Load Balancer IPs, the Lambda function updates the S3 text file with new IP addresses and sends email notification using SNS.
3. Utilize something similar to the above, but use local scripts

Comment: This looks like exaclty what's needed, thanks for the suggestions. I understand that we're not able to receieve prior warning to ALB updates from AWS but this is the next best thing.